# Redirecionamento 301 pelo htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, redirecionamento

Preciso fazer alguns redirecionamentos 301 das `urls` do meu site que mudou e está em subdominio, como realizo essas alterações no `htaccess`?

Antes meu site acessava: www.meusite.com.br/contato

Agora está assim: www.meusite.com.br/site/contato

Comment: Já tentou assim: `Redirect 301 /contato http://meusite.com.br/site/contato/` ?

Comment: já sim, não está dando certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui através da `RedirectMatch 301`

ai ficou

```
RedirectMatch 301 contato/ http://www.meusite.com.br/site/contato
```